# Visual Studio Community can't find any libraries after migrating to new CPU

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently migrated my old Macbook Pro (15 inch 2018) to a new one (16 inch 2019). Not much of a difference between the two, OS-wise. However on my new machine Visual Studio Community, which I use to code C# with Unity, suddenly doesn't recognize a single standard library, including UnityEngine or System. The game runs fine, but the script files are a mess of red underlines.

[image: Screenshot of the mess]

Stuff I've tried...

1. Upgrading Unity to latest version
2. Closing and re-opening visual studio community
3. Restarting my computer
4. Making some small changes to files
5. Selecting "Build"/"Rebuild All"  (Hangs on "Cleaning solution" until I close the program, even if I leave it open hours).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this annoying issue?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There are 2 things  I can suggest you first check and make sure that you have all the necessary add on installing for visual studio, Another thing is that, check your **Edit>Prefrance>External Tool>External Script Editor** is set to Visual studio. hope it helps

Comment: Have you installed the latest Visual Studio package in Unity (Windows -> Package Manager)?

Comment: @ColinYoung That did it! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the latest Visual Studio package is installed in Unity: Windows -> Package Manager.

Similarly if you are using Rider or Visual Studio Code.